# Loop over columns in OLD and NEW

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to do something that I thought was fairly simple. Produce a comma delimited list of columns that changed in an update. e.g. for a table foo:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = 8, zoo = "it's a zoo in here";
```

Using an `AFTER` update trigger on foo I should then be able to loop over the table columns, comparing `OLD.col` with `NEW.col` to determine if it changed, and produce a string "bar, zoo".

It's easy if you hardcode the column names but that's not an option for me. *Getting the column names is easy enough, but how to dynamically get the values from `NEW` and `OLD` to compare them?* Is there any way at all to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using `information_schema` views to dynamically query for columns in the table. Then you could use cursor to iterate over the resultset. That could be tricky. I don't know if cursors are supported within triggers.

Comment: I think you can use cursors in triggers, but the problem is how can you access the values from OLD and NEW using column names from the cursor?

Comment: Use prepared statements to build queries within cursor.

Comment: Can't use prepared statements in triggers in MySQL :(

Comment: @Mchl can you elaborate on your answer, or provide a link on how to do that? It's exactly what I need to do...check columns that are different to generate a new update statement for a sync process